# How to prevent tha page refresh after click the cancel button in confirmation alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to stop the page refresh after click on the cancel button in the alert box. This the way i am trying

```
$(".settings").click(function(event){
 var con = (confirm("This some text. Are you sure?"))
 if (con == false)
 {
   return false;
 }
 else
 {

    }   
});
```

`.setting` is the gear icon class in the `span tag`. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: can you show us the html code?

Comment: Please check if some other event is also triggered, e.g. when you add `data-remote=true` in the link, which would cause the behaviour you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Use `preventDefault()` as shown :-

```
$(".settings").click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var con = confirm("This some text. Are you sure?")
   if (con == false){
     // ....
   }
   else{
     // ....
   }
});
```

OR(use `return false`)

```
$(".settings").click(function(){
   var con = confirm("This some text. Are you sure?")
   if (con == false){
     // ....
   }
   else{
     // ....
   }
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Earlier i tried with this `event.preventDefault();` but it's not work for me.

Comment: This is also not working. i am tried with `event.cancelBubble = true;` `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: @Rajini...this is not possible..plz post your complete code of jquery and html also...the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: i render the partial into that particular view page.

Comment: is the event even triggered, did you try console.log(1) inside function() {} ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".settings").click(function(event){
   var con = (confirm("This some text. Are you sure?"))
   if (con == true)
   {
      //do something
   }
   else
   {
       //stop page refresh after click cancel
        event.preventDefault();
   }   
});
```

Comment: The preventDefault() method cancels the event if it is cancelable, meaning that the default action that belongs to the event will not occur.
Note: Not all events are cancelable. Use the cancelable property to find out if an event is cancelable.
Note: The preventDefault() method does not prevent further propagation of an event through the DOM. Use the stopPropagation() method to handle this.
So preventDefault might not be the ultimate solution. The question asked has some ambiguity which might need further investigation.